# How can I load .xsd file to track relationships(nesting) between elements?

Tags: c#, .net, xsd

I know, where is `XmlSchema` class in dot net, but it does not allow to load file into it. Is there a clean solution to load xsd file and travel between elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`XmlSchemaSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaset.aspx), e.g.:

```
XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();

schemaSet.Add(targetNamespace, schemaUri);
schemaSet.Compile();

foreach(XmlSchemaElement element in schemaSet.GlobalElements.Values)
{
    // do stuff...
}
```

**EDIT:** Sorry for not being clearer.

Where the comment says `// do stuff...`, what you need to do is traverse the inherited types of each element, which are available under [`XmlSchemaElement.SchemaType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaelement.schematype.aspx), and the inline type of the element, which is available under [`XmlSchemaElement.ElementSchemaType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaelement.elementschematype.aspx).

The MSDN does contain all the the information you're after, but it is somewhat maze-like and requires digging around plus a bit of trial-and-error to work it out.

As per my comment, the following class from one of my open-source side-projects may be of use to you here:

http://bitbucket.org/philbooth/schemabrute/src/tip/LibSchemaBrute/Navigator.cs

Comment: Ok, I got all global elements, but how can I get child elements of this global elements? I tried everything, but it seems what XmlSchemaElement has not have references on it child elements.

Comment: Okay, that is too complicated a question to answer fully in one of these comments, but essentially you need to analyse the `SchemaType` and `ElementSchemaType` members of `XmlSchemaElement`. The MSDN does contain all the details, but you need to do some digging for it to become clear. If you post another question I can help more, otherwise you could take a look at one of my little side-projects that does this stuff. The class you should look at is called LibSchemaBrute::Navigator ~ http://bitbucket.org/philbooth/schemabrute/src/tip/LibSchemaBrute/Navigator.cs

Answer (score -1):

I suggest checking out this tool: http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html.  You can create a data model from any XSD file.  I've used it in many XML projects.

Comment: Sorry, I don't need any tool, I need programmatic advice.

Comment: I'm sorry you don't need a tool.  I realize you don't necessarily need tools to complete a task.  Tools allow you to work faster and more efficiently.  I would suggest anyone working with XML try the tool because it will save a lot of time and is very useful.  Thanks

Comment: -1 sounds a bit too much spam to me, this is not related to the question.